# Where did the day counter go?

Tags: support, profile-page

Before the profile change I was always able to see a counter on my profile indicating how many times I had logged on, etc. I know it is not important, but I found it cool. For some reason I can't seem to find it anymore. Does it still exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you access *your own* user profile, the site shows you the *Activity* tab. The day counter is on the *Profile* tab:

[image: profile]

So, go to *Profile* tab; the days are shown on the right.

[image: days]

The circled line is clickable: it opens a calendar that gives a day-by-day account of your visits.